# Open Facebook Messenger to text directly to my page

Tags: java, android, facebook, messenger

I wanna introduce in my app an action that allows the user to text me faster through Facebook Messenger directly to my Facebook Page.

I will place a button "Contact me" and - clicking - will pop up Facebook Messenger ready to text me to my Page.
I don't want open my Facebook Page, I want open the chat with my Facebook page.

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean like allowing your app to wrap around the FB messenger, so it would appear within your app? Your question is not so clear.

Comment: @AntonA. that's what I was looking for! I couldn't find in any place, THANK YOU